# Rake handle screw keeps falling off

Tags: screws, landscaping, hand-tools

I keep having the same problem with leaf rakes.  This screw works its way loose and it gets lost while raking.  I have replaced it and kept going, but it is annoying.   Is there any way to lock it in place?  It holds the plastic rake head onto the hollow metal handle.

[image]
The rake in this picture is a new one, with the original screw.  But many other similar ones have failed

Comment: "many other similar ones have failed" -- to me, that would be sign to stop buying this kind of rake and similar ones, and look for something better designed and well made. Tools like this ought to last for ages.

Comment: superglue it in place

Comment: @DanMašek You should promote this comment to a full frame challenge answer.

Answer (score 11):

A long enough machine screw or bolt with a lock nut will work.

Drill a hole though both sides of the plastic rake using the screw hole as a guide.

Take out that screw and measure the inside of the the hole to find size of bolt/screw you can use.  Offhand maybe a 10 or 12 screw or 3/16 bolt.

With a lock nut you do not need to tighten down hard(cracking the plastic) for it to hold, just touch the plastic.

Edit   The proper name for the the locking nut is a nyloc nut, as per the nice comment. They have a piece of plastic that jams/locks the threads together but is easy to undo.  Used when the nut does not/cannot be tighten down to use a lock washer.

Comment: A nyloc nut might be a good option, here, too

Comment: @SiHa  Thanks for the name, what I was thinking of, but could not think of the proper name.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend using something like Loc-tite or a lock washer on the screw. Usually the metal handle is thin so nothing will last as long as you want it too.

Comment: If I like the tool, sometimes will buy/replace those metal handles with a wooden one.

Comment: Loctite reacts badly with plastic and causes it to break. You want super glue here

Comment: @DKNguyen Does the plastic go all the way around?  Or is the metal pole visible on the other side?  (It's hard to tell which from the photo.)  If so, then the part of the screw with the Loctite on it doesn't need to be anywhere near the plastic, just on the pole-side where the nut attaches.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman True. If the plastic doesn't go all the way around it can go on the other side where it is just metal-on-metal.

Answer (score 5):

1. Drill through and put a bolt completely through, with a nut on the other side.  A nylock nut will not come off by itself. 
    The screw is coming out because its a coarse thread a thin sheet metal tube, so there are few threads engaged and minimal friction.

---

2. A large pop-rivet will work well, IF you have one that fills the hole almost completely.  Small ones will just rattle around and fall out - ideally a rivet whose shaft diameter is just under the hole size.

---

3. Remove handle from head, and clean both mating surfaces of dirt.  Scuff the paint with sandpaper or a file, and do what you can inside the socket. 
    Mix up some 2 part epoxy and liberally wipe it on the handle, then drive it into the socket firmly.  Ideally have enough spill to form a gusset around the socket hole and up the handle a little.  Once that has cured (wait 24 hours regardless if its 5 minute or 1 hour epoxy) then it should be a lifetime bond.  
    Downside, you'll need a lot of force to replace the handle/head in the future.

Comment: +1 for pop rivet - you beat me to it! Maybe even another on the opposite side too. At least they can be drilled out to replace handle or head - if you could be bothered.

Answer (score 3):

A small dab of rubber cement on the threads of the screw just before you screw it in should help.

Answer (score 1):

If, like me, you collect random old screws, then you will probably find a slightly longer or wider screw in your hoard. Each time any securing screw works loose, replace it with a slightly bigger one.

Comment: Eventually, you're looking for a screw the diameter of the handle, but until then, this isn't a bad idea! :)

Comment: @FreeMan : Unlikely that a plastic rake would last that long.